# Getting garbage value when trying to get the value from Private Array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, garbage

I have created a class called Array in which there is a static Array . I have made this Array as private.

```
    class Array
{
    private:
    int A[10] ;
    int size;
    int length;
```

I want to access the value of the elements of this array. For this I have created one get function which would return the values of elements at different positions.

```
int Array::Get(int x)
{
    return A[x];
}
```

But when I try to print the value of the particular element after inserting elements in array it throws some garbage value.

Full CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Array
{
    private:
    int A[10] ;
    int size;
    int length;
   public:
   Array()
   {
       A[10];
       size =10;
       length = 0;
   }
   Array(int sz)
   {
       int A[10];
       size = sz;
       length = 0;
   }

    void Display();
    void Append(int x);
    int Get(int x);
   
};
int Array::Get(int x)
{
    return A[x];
}
void Array::Display ()
{
    cout << "\n Elements are\n";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
    {
        cout<<A[i]<<" ";
    }
}
void Array::Append(int x)
{
 if(length<size)
 A[length++]=x;
 
}
int main()
{
    Array arr1;
    int si = 10;
    arr1= Array(si);
    cout << "enter the elements here" << endl;
    int x;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < si ; i++)
    {
        printf("enter the  element %d \n " , i);
        scanf("%d",&x);
        arr1.Append(x);
        
    }
    arr1.Display() ;
    int count;
    count = arr1.Get(0);
    printf("%d" , &count);
   



}
```

Comment: please include input, output and expected output in the quesiton

Comment: `printf("%d" , &count);` looks *very* odd (and wrong: use `%p` for a pointer).  What are you trying to do there?

Comment: Fyi, both `A[10];` in `Array::Array()` and `int A[10];` in `Array::Array(int sz)` are either nonsense, pointless, or both. What C++ resource are you learning from that is showing you this?

Comment: `A[10];` does nothing except cause undefined behaviour, and `int A[10];` declares a local variable. Read about arrays and scope in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: @AdityaSharma Use a `std::vector` as it can be resized. You're using array which can't be resized. And use `cout` instead of `printf`.

Comment: `&count` is the location of `count`, not its value. Are you confusing `printf` with `scanf`? (Stick to C++ I/O instead.)

Comment: if he wants a fixed size array, he can as well use `std::array<T,N>`. Unless of course this is another of those students on certain India Universities who still learn "c++" with Borland C++ 3.0 on a x86 DOS machine.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are a ***c*** developer or used to use ***c***.

Thanks guys for pointing out bad lines in your code.

I tried your code in my IDE and fixed it, but I think you need to study more in the classes. I am a beginner but I noticed these mistakes in your code.
First, when you want to create an array of flexible size, you should not give it a fixed size.

As you did in your class member variables:

```
private:
    int A[10] ;
    int size;
    int length;
```

You already gave it a size of 10, but in the constructors you created a constructor that tries to resize the array:

```
Array(int sz)
{
   int A[10];
   size = sz;
   length = 0;
}
```

Also when you try to get the number x of your array:

```
int number;
count = arr1.Get(0);
printf("%d" , &count);
```

You are specifying the address of the variable count, not its value.

Here is your fixed code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Array {
private:
  int *A;
  int size;
  int length;

public:
  Array() {
    //   default constructor
    A = new int[10];
    size = 10;
    length = 0;
  }
  Array(int sz) {
    //   change the size of array
    size = sz;
    A = new int[sz];
    length = 0;
  }

  ~Array(){
  delete [] A;
   }

  void Display();
  void Append(int x);
  int Get(int x);
};
int Array::Get(int x) {
  if (x < length)
    return A[x];
  else {
    std::cerr << "number is out of rang\n\a";
    return 0;
  }
}
void Array::Display() {
  cout << "\n Elements are\n";
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    cout << A[i] << " ";
  }
}
void Array::Append(int x) {
  if (length < size)
    A[length++] = x;
}

int main() {

  int si;
  //  changing size
  //    int newsize;
  //    std::cout << "enter size of your array : ";
  //    std::cin >> newsize;
  //    si = newsize;
  //    Array arr2(newsize);
  //  default constructor with size 10
  Array arr1;
  si = 10;
  //  no need to this
  // arr1= Array(si);
  cout << "enter the elements here" << endl;
  int x;
  for (int i = 0; i < si; i++) {
    std::cout << "enter number " << i + 1 << " : ";
    std::cin >> x;
    arr1.Append(x);
  }
  arr1.Display();
  int chose;
  std::cout << "enter number to find in array : ";
  std::cin >> chose;
  int num = arr1.Get(chose);
  //  if chose is not out of array range
  if (num)
    std::cout << "number " << chose << " in array is : " << num << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't look so great. Class as is does not follow [the rule of 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), `std::vector` should be used here. "created a constructor that tries to resize" - not at all, OP simply confused local variable with class member.

Comment: I know he should use ***std::vector*** but I tried to make his own codes and about the of rule 3, as I said I am also a beginner and I just figured it out ,  thank you for pointing this out.